# Why does PoE use 4 wires to deliver power?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, ethernet, poe

I know Ethernet uses differential signaling that's why you need 2 wires for transmit and another 2 wires for receive.

But what about power? Why are 4 wires used?

Comment: Two wires are more flexible than one wire twice as thick?

Comment: Deliver moar power without changing the cable or voltage?

Comment: I believe, power transmission happens via common mode voltage between two signal pairs

Answer (score 2):

There are power options for recent (100baseT and gigabit) twisted pair
wiring, that were never available in previous generations of the standard.

The four wires used for power are also carrying signals, so
they aren't "extra" wiring.

The modern power-over-Ethernet (poE) solutions use a center-tapped signal transformer
winding on both the power supplying and power using ends of the link,
which means that while they use four wires, they do not use UP those
four wires.   The signals are difference voltages from/to the ends of
the primary windings, while the power currents are delivered to/taken from
the center taps of the secondary (long-transmission-line side) windings, so there's no interference
between power and signal functions.

For gigabit Ethernet, four pairs (eight wires) carry four signal lanes, and usually two pairs (four wires) carry poE power; the two pairs used are those wires that
were not utilized in earlier (100baseT and 10baseT) slower twisted pair Ethernet,
so the scheme is widely compatible with existing equipment.

Comment: So basically, the magic is in the transformer?